# Are "Meta Quest" questions off-topic here?

Tags: support

On [gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-quest-2) are only questions about Gaming on Meta Quest welcome. The VR headset has many more use cases.

Meta Quest is based on Android. Are Meta Quest questions here on topic? A quick search didn't find any question about the Zuck empire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any VR headset, the important question is: does it have anything to do with Android, or otherwise something that Android experts (regardless of being VR experts) can likely answer?

There are at least 2 VR-related tags on Android.SE currently:

- [samsung-gear-vr](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-gear-vr)
- [daydream-vr](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daydream-vr)

So, questions about Meta Quest are likely on-topic here, as long as it's related to Android itself (e.g. how to connect the headset, how to use the Meta Quest Android app, etc.)

As for why there's no question about Meta Quest, well... because no one has asked about it? So, be the first one to ask :)

Comment: Meta Quest devices have Android as their [onboard operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_Quest_Pro).